# Spring RestController RestMapping hierarchy

Tags: java, spring

I have a REST application and its working.
Now, im trying to add a superpath (an environment) like this:

Actual Path: http://localhost:8080/myApp/entityList1/
Desired New Path: http://localhost:8080/myApp/environments/{envId}/entityList1/

I tried to "foward" the controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/environments")
public class EnvironmetController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Environment> getList() {
        return EnvironmentDAO.getInstance().getList();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{envId}/entityList1")
    public EntityList1Controller getEntityList1(@PathVariable int envId) {
        return new EntityList1Controller(envId);
    }
```

The EntityList1Controller  its like this:

```
@RestController
public class EntityList1Controller  {

  private int envId;

  public EntityList1Controller() {
  }

  public EntityList1Controller(int envId) {
     this.envId = envId
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Entity1> getList() {
            return Entity1DAO.getInstance().getList(envId);
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. It throws an AmbigousError with the GET method.

I didnt find if i could do this kind of "controller forwarding" or i have to configure something else.

Any help will be appreciated

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems;

> I didnt find if i could do this kind of "controller forwarding"

In EnvironmetController, you are returning a new instance of the EntityList controller. You need to apply the redirect the servletResponse like this, but you also need the envId (to make it REST-like).

```
@RequestMapping("/{envId}/entityList1")
public void getEntityList1(
    final HttpServletResponse response,
    final @PathVariable Integer envId) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/enitytList1/" + 
        Integer.toString(envId));
}
```

> It throws an AmbigousError with the GET method

Make sure you have the correct annotation on your EntityList1Controller, sounds like the the two GET handlers are mapped to the same endpoint;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/enitytList1")
public class EntityList1Controller {
```

and your handler should have the correction annotation;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{envId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Entity1> getList(@PathVariable ("envId") Integer envId) {
    return Entity1DAO.getInstance().getList(envId);
}
```

This should forward requests from myApp/environments/{envId}/entityList1/ to myApp/enitytList1/{envId} which is close to what you want, but you will need the envId in the request.

It's unusual to use redirection in rest, but hope this sets you in the right direction.

**EDIT** And don't call constructors on Controllers directly, let Spring make the singletons for you.